# Adding records from salesforce to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, salesforce, integration

I have a requirement, for example:

An account record has a checkbox 'isClosed'. Whenever the checkbox is made true, I want this Account record (including name,Revenue etc.) to be stored in AWS S3.

Is this possible to push a record?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Amazon AppFlow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appflow/latest/userguide/salesforce.html) to trigger a flow when data changes on `Account` objects in Salesforce. AppFlow can then send data to an Amazon S3 bucket.

You must enable **change data capture** in Salesforce to use event-driven flow triggers. See: [Select Objects for Change Notifications in the User Interface | Change Data Capture Developer Guide | Salesforce Developers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_select_objects.htm)

Comment: Amazon AppFlow works perfectly fine, thanks. But is there any way if I can use REST POST callout to push values into S3?

Comment: You might be able to do something like: [Upload binary stream to Amazon S3 using REST API PUT operation - Salesforce Developer Community](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BMDFIA4)